# Continuity of the function $\frac{1}{log(x)}$

Tags: limits, continuity, graphing-functions

The graph of log(x) is [image]

When you're graphing $\frac{1}{log(x)}$;
[image]

Why is it that the reciprocal of log|x| at x=0 is taken to be 0, I.e., why is it continuous there? Isn't it just a limiting value towards infinity? Conversely, on zooming into the second graph (I plotted it online) f(0 never really touches 0).

Why does that happen, too?

Comment: As a limit, what is $log0$?

Comment: Log0 is not defined, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it that the reciprocal of log|x| at x=0 is taken to be 0?

It isn't taken to be 0. 
At $x = 0$, neither $\log|x|$ nor $\frac{1}{\log|x|}$
exist.

However, the $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\log|x|}$ does exist and is equal to $0.$

**Addendum**
Per user request

> Shouldn't the second graph have a hole there, then?

**Absolutely**.  At $x=0$, neither $\log x$ nor $\frac{1}{\log x}$ exist.  I think the thickness of the line in the graph is misleading.

Comment: Shouldn't the second graph have a hole there, then?

Comment: Right, thanks. Can you add that to the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The log function $\log_e x \equiv \ln x$ is not defined at $x=0$. More precisely, it is only defined for $x >0$. You are correct when you're saying that this is a "limiting value".

Specifically, it is:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \ln x = - \infty \implies \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\ln x} = 0.$$

The thickness of the plotted line does seem misleading, but the value $0$ does **not** belong to the function plotted - thus it should have a "hole" there.

Comment: So is the graph correct? And is it technically continuous there?

Comment: It is not continuous, there is a hole in the graph at the origin. A removable discontinuity if you wish

Comment: The graph is correct, but it does **not** take $0$ as a value of the function plotted. The thickness of the line is kind of mis-leading, precisely there should be a "hole" or exactly as imranfat said, a removable discontinuity.